# Regex to remove spaces between invalid HTML tags - i.e. "< / b >" should be "</b>"

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have some HTML that is all mangled with the spaces within the tags and wants to make it valid again - for example:

```
< div class='test' >1 > 0 is < b >true</ b> and apples >>> bananas< / div >
```

Should be converted to valid HTML and when rendered, it would expectedly produce:

```html
<div class='test'>1 > 0 is <b>true</b> and apples >>> bananas</div>
```

Any `>` or `<` preceded/followed by spaces in the text should be left unchanged - for example, `1 > 0` should remain, rather than being squashed to `1>0`

I realize this will probably take a couple of regex expressions, which is fine

I have a few things:

`<\s?\/\s*` which will partially fix `</ b>< / div >` to `</b></div >`, but am struggling with the rest

For example, I could go with a heavy-handed approach, but this will also break code within the text parts of the tags, rather than the tag names themselves

Comment: It's also mangled in that you cannot have raw HTML metacharacters like `>` in the text. They must be written as, or replaced by, proper entities like `&gt;`.

Comment: Since you'd really need to convert the special characters `<`, `>` etc that are not a part of any tags to their correct html entities, you'll need an actual XML parser, not regex. [Regex cannot properly parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2691058)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works too:

It captures valid sections in an HTML tag in four parts and replaces the rest (spaces) with that.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6zGJ4P/1)

`/(<)\s*(\/?)\s*([^<>]*\S)\s*(>)/g`

- `(<)` - capture starting angular bracket (section 1)
- `\s*` - match any spaces
- `(\/?)` - capture optional backward slash (section 2)
- `\s*` - match any spaces after the backward slash
- `([^<>]*\S)` - capture the content inside the tag without the trailing spaces (section 3)
- `\s*` - match spaces after the content and before the closing angular bracket
- `(>)` - capture the closing angular bracket (section 4)

```js
const reg = /(<)\s*(\/?)\s*([^<>]*\S)\s*(>)/g
const str = "< div class='test' >1 > 0 is < b >true< / b > and apples >>> bananas< / div  >"
const newStr = str.replace(reg, "$1$2$3$4");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Nice, that seems to work on some other test data too. I will try with my real data and check if it works. I'll mark this as the best answer, if it does

Comment: why capture literals?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reasonable way to save a document as corrupt as what you've posted, but assuming you replace the `>` and similar characters in the text the their relevant entities, eg: `&gt;`, you can massage the document to be accepted into a proper library like [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) which will handle the rest.

```php
$input = <<<_E_
< div class='test' >1 &gt; 0 is < b >true</ b> and apples &gt;&gt;&gt; bananas< / div >
_E_;

$input = preg_replace([ '#<\s+#', '#</\s+#' ], [ '<', '</' ], $input);

$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($input, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

var_dump($d->saveHTML());
```

Output:

```
string(80) "<div class="test">1 &gt; 0 is <b>true</b> and apples &gt;&gt;&gt; bananas</div>"
```

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe I will try and proper parser, rather than regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of `.replace()`s with a RegEx and a custom replace callback:

```js
let s = `< div class='test' >1 > 0 is < b >true</ b> and apples >>> bananas< / div >`;

s = s.replace(/<.*?>/g, m => m.replaceAll(' ', '').replace(m.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)[0], tagName => tagName + ' ').replace(' >', '>')
);

console.log(s);
```

Here's a breakdown of the RegExs:

1. `s.replace(/<.*?>/g, /* arrow function */)`

This will run the long arrow function as the custom replacer function for everything inside of the `<` and `>` brackets. This way, the replacement will only affect inside the tags. The arrow function takes one parameter, `m`, which is the original text, and returns text to replace it with.

2. `m.replaceAll(' ', '')`

Removes all spaces in the string. This will also remove spaces between the tag name and the attributes, so we need step 3.

3. `.replace(m.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)[0], tagName => tagName + ' ')`

This takes the result of step 2 and adds a space after each tag name. `m.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)[0]` will be the tag name because `m` still contains the original text before step 2.

4. `.replace(' >', '>')`

This will get the last edge case where there were no attributes or the tag was an ending tag so step 3 actually added an unnecessary space.

Comment: Thanks, this gets further than my approach. @Amila's answer seems to fix all the issues (at least on the test data I have tried so far...), so you might be interested in seeing how that works too